# How to validate email address inputs?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have an ASP.NET web form where I can can enter an email address.

I need to validate that field with acceptable email addresses ONLY in the below pattern:

```
xxx@home.co.uk
xxx@home.com
xxx@homegroup.com
```

Comment: This is one of those things that people point out as a classic use of regular expressions that is annoyingly hard to get right.  The simple fact that there are so many answers pointing out bugs in other people's answers just goes to prove it.  And that's the reason I try to avoid regular expressions for well-known stuff like email addresses, URLs, etc.  Use a library.

Comment: In this case, however, just using a library means validation after the postback rather than validation on the form.  Some code is difficult to write, but still worth writing.

Answer (score 7):

A regular expression to validate this would be:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+((@home\.co\.uk)|(@home\.com)|(@homegroup\.com))$
```

C# sample:

```
string emailAddress = "jim@home.com";
string pattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+((@home\.co\.uk)|(@home\.com)|(@homegroup\.com))$";
if (Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    // email address is valid
}
```

VB sample:

```
Dim emailAddress As String = "jim@home.com"
Dim pattern As String = "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+((@home\.co\.uk)|(@home\.com)|(@homegroup\.com))$";
If Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
    ' email address is valid
End If
```

Comment: Guys none of your expressions are working; I checked it by putting your expressions as a regular expression validator property value.

Control is not validating.

Please see my question again; there is no  homebase anywhere .. and i wonder how homebase came in answers :-o

Comment: @Jaison: You're right it must've slipped in somewhere inbetween. But then again, it's easy to fix. s/base/group/ ;-)

Comment: @Jaison, it seems the error started on my answer and everyone else copied my mistake, fundamental schoolboy error lol, but it doesn't take a genius to fix

Comment: If you use the ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator object, you will need to include `[a-z]` as well as `[A-Z]`, because it is case-specific.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I would do the validation using `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`:

```
bool valid = true;
try
{
    MailAddress address = new MailAddress(email);
}
catch(FormatException)
{
    valid = false;
}

if(!(email.EndsWith("@home.co.uk") || 
     email.EndsWith("@home.com") || 
     email.EndsWith("@homegroup.com")))
{
    valid = false;
}

return valid;
```

`MailAddress` first validates that it is a valid email address.  Then the rest validates that it ends with the destinations you require.  To me, this is simpler for everyone to understand than some clumsy-looking regex.  It may not be as performant as a regex would be, but it doesn't sound like you're validating a bunch of them in a loop ... just one at a time on a web page

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what version of ASP.NET your are using you can use one of the Form Validation controls in your toolbox under 'Validation.'  This is probably preferable to setting up your own logic after a postback.  There are several types that you can drag to your form and associate with controls, and you can customize the error messages and positioning as well.

There are several types that can make it a required field or make sure its within a certain range, but you probably want the Regular Expression validator.  You can use one of the expressions already shown or I think Visual Studio might supply a sample email address one.

Comment: Also +1, good answer to suggest the use of a validation control, especially pointing out the regex validator control.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you should NOT replace back-end validation with client-side validation. You SHOULD definitely use them both, or server-side only, but never only client-side. The validation controls are excellent, but not a replacement for real server-side validation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

See e.g. here:

http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/news/csharp_0101.html

Answer (score 1):

I second the use of a regex, however Patrick's regex won't work (wrong alternation). Try:

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@home(\.co\.uk|(group)?\.com)
```

And don't forget to escape backslashes in a string that you use in source code, depending on the language used.

```
"[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@home(\\.co\\.uk|(group)?\\.com)"
```

Comment: Guys none of your expressions are working; I checked it by putting your expressions as a regular expression validator property value.

Control is not validating.

Please see my question again; there is no  homebase anywhere .. and i wonder how homebase came in answers :-o

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official regex from **RFC 2822**, which will match any proper email address:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: Guys none of your expressions are working; I checked it by putting your expressions as a regular expression validator property value.

Control is not validating.

Please see my question again; there is no  homebase anywhere .. and i wonder how homebase came in answers :-o


when i given cdfsdf@home1.com it is validating ..its shouldnt validate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex matcher = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\@((home\.co\.uk)|(home\.com)|(homegroup\.com))");

if(matcher.IsMatch(theEmailAddressToCheck))
{
    //Allow it
}
else
{
    //Don't allow it
}
```

You'll need to add the Regex namespace to your class too:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: Be careful of your dots, your expression will match anyone@homexco,uk for example

Comment: Yeah you're right - could you explain what the backslashes on yours do to fix that issue please? Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see now - just a dot is any character, but \. = a literal .

Cool thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An extension method to do this would be:

```
public static bool ValidEmail(this string email)
    {
        var emailregex = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+(@home\.co\.uk$)|(@home\.com$)|(@homegroup\.com$)");
        var match = emailregex.Match(email);
        return match.Success;
    }
```

Comment: Guys none of your expressions are working; I checked it by putting your expressions as a regular expression validator property value.

Control is not validating.

Please see my question again; there is no  homebase anywhere .. and i wonder how homebase came in answers :-o

Comment: "homebase" in not mentioned anywhere in my code. I ran some tests and found that they passed except when using an email address like "test@homegroup.common". This passed when it should have failed. To fix this I added the $ to match the expression to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ../>` with the regular expression in the ValidateExpression property.

Comment: I know it's a 10 year old answer, but the guy needs to know *what* regular expression to write; he already knows he needs to use regular expression validation.

Answer (score -1):

Patricks' answer seems pretty well worked out but has a few flaws.

- You do want to group parts of the regex but don't want to capture them. Therefore you'll need to use non-capturing parenthesis.
- The alternation is partly wrong.
- It does not test if this was part of the string or the entire string
- It uses [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) instead of [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx).

A better solution in C# would be:

```
string emailAddress = "someone@home.co.uk";
if (Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@home(?:\.co\.uk|(?:group)?\.com)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    // email address is valid
}
```

Of course to be completely sure that all email addresses pass you can use a more thorough expression:

```
string emailAddress = "someone@home.co.uk";
if (Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, @"^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@home(?:\.co\.uk|(?:group)?\.com)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    // email address is valid
}
```

Comment: LOL...good catch...that'll teach me to read the question properly :)

Comment: Hi Huppie, can you tell me if my alternation part is still wrong?  I have updated my answer, have you any more comments on it?

Comment: did you guys see homebase in my question?