# Eliminating multiple periods in sequence

Tags: .net, regex, email

I am using this regex in .NET to validate email addresses:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9](([\w,=\.!\-#|\$%\^&*\+/\?\{\}~]+)*)[\w,=!\-#|\$%\^&*\+/\?\{\}~])@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$
```

One issue with it though: In the local name before the `@` symbol, it accepts multiple periods in sequence. For example, `ab...c@gmail.com`.

Does anyone know how I can fix that and yet keep the rest of the logic intact?

Thanks

Comment: is this another duplicate of your "closed because of duplication" question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263853/regular-expression-for-email-closed

Comment: I'm probably just being dense, but where does that regex mention dots? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: There are 2 unmatched closing brackets.

Comment: Ooops!!!
"^([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9](([\w,=\.!\-#|\$%\^&\*\+/\?`\{\}~]+)*)[\w,=!\-#|\$%\^&\*\+/\?`\{\}~])@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$"

Somehow while copying made a mess of it..
Sorry about that!

Comment: bjelli - That problem was resolved..Its another issue with the same regex.

Comment: If I "edit" the question, the expression appears correctly ..dont know why:(

Answer (score 1):

```
while (email.contains(".."))
 email = email.Replace("..",".");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the code behind.
The only thing I am allowed to change here is the regex :(

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent contiguous periods before the '@' the same way you're preventing them *after* it:

```
^
[A-Za-z0-9][\w,=!#|$%^&*+/?{}~-]+
(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9][\w,=!#|$%^&*+/?{}~-]+)*
@
(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+
[a-zA-Z]{2,9}
$
```

You'll need to remove the line breaks; I broke it up for readability, since it won't all fit on one line anyway.  Got rid of a lot of things that weren't pulling their weight, too.